# Adding Alpha-Beta prunning to minMax in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

Hi there I have problems adding [alpha beta pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning) to my minMax algorithm for the connect 4  game can you help me ? here is my code for the minMax procedure, it looks to me that there is just a little that have to be done what eludes me :S scoreBoard() is my Heuristics function and I returning an array with 2 values the first one is the position of on the table and the other one is the score for this position.

```
-(NSArray*) miniMaxWihtAlphaBetaPrunning:(BOOL)maxOrMin withAlpha:(NSInteger)alpha
 withBeta:(NSInteger)beta withPlayer:(enum playerColor)player andTreeDepth:
(NSInteger)depth
{
if (depth == 0)
{
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-1],
[NSNumber  numberWithInt:scoreBoard()],nil];
}
else
{
    NSInteger bestScore = maxOrMin ? redWins: blueWins;
    NSInteger bestMove = -1;

    for (NSInteger column = 0; column < 10; column++)
    {
        if (discPlacedMatrix[0][column] != 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        NSInteger rowFilled = dropDiscAtPoint(column, player);

        if (rowFilled == -1)
        {
            continue;
        }

        NSInteger s = scoreBoard();

        if (s == (maxOrMin? blueWins : redWins))
        {
            bestMove = column;
            bestScore = s;
            discPlacedMatrix[rowFilled][column] = 0;

            break;
        }

        NSArray* result =  [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self miniMaxWihtAlphaBetaPrunning:!maxOrMin withAlpha:alpha withBeta:beta withPlayer:(player == 1 ? RED : BLUE) andTreeDepth:depth - 1]];

        NSInteger scoreInner = [[result objectAtIndex:1] intValue];

        discPlacedMatrix[rowFilled][column] = 0;

        if (scoreInner == blueWins || scoreInner == redWins)
        {
            scoreInner -= depth * player;
        }
        if (maxOrMin)
        {
            if (scoreInner >= bestScore)
            {
                bestScore = scoreInner;
                bestMove = column;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (scoreInner <= bestScore)
            {
                bestScore = scoreInner;
                bestMove = column;
            }
        }
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:bestMove],[NSNumber numberWithInt:bestScore],nil];
}
```

}

I tried some scenarios but the Ai started to

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is; can you clarify what problem you're having?

Comment: I need to add the alpha - beta prunning to the miniMax procedure,it is only the miniMax at the moment as you can see I am not currently using the alpha beta values in the function i have them only as parameters :) the point is that I tried adding it a few times in a few different ways but the AI started to play really bad :(

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something like the **jamboree algorithm**.  The basic idea of this algorithm is to go through your tree recursively, and at each level, run the alpha beta algorithm on part of the nodes at that level, and then run the mini-max algorithm on the rest of the nodes.  I'm at work right now, but I'll elaborate when I get home.

An implementation:
http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Jamboree